# What is the scope of a class decorated with the JavaEE Singleton annotation?

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, apache-tomee

I am interested to know the scope of an instance of a class that is marked with the `javax.ejb.Singleton` annotation.

I am working on a web application that contsists of 6 separate REST applications. These 6 applications are compiled to wars, and are all deployed inside the same TomEE webserver.

I was forced to use the Singleton annotation because I needed a way to share data between a servlet filter and services code, and the scope of normal beans seemed to not be shared between the filter and the application. For that purpose, the Singleton seems to work fine (although I dont like the idea of using Singleton, and I am on the lookout for an alternative approach).

Anyway, now that I am using Singleton, I have a doubt about its scope.

Is the scope of a Singleton instance limited to within each webapp (one of the deployed webapps would not be able to see the same Singleton as another webapp within the same TomEE), or does the webserver somehow share a Singleton amongst all deployed webapps ?

Comment: Aren't Singletons global scope within a web app?  It's part of the reason why they're a bad idea.  No sharing across web apps.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, `@Singleton` EJBs are strictly scoped within their respective application; they might as well be on two different server instances. If you have a reproducible test case to prove the opposite on your favourite EE container - in this case TomEE - its developers will thank you for a bug report. And probably will treat it with high priority.

As for your use case: It is always a bad idea to increase the scope, just so components, which are normally not enabled to communicate with each other, can do so. Establish proper communication channels between your software components, and all will fall into place.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Its good to be assured that the scope of Singleton is the particular application. I was not saying that I have a case where Singleton has a scope beyond an application, I am saying that the scope of ApplicationScoped seemed to not include a servlet filter, but the scope of Singleton does. For that reason I was forced to use Singleton. Regarding the question of whether or now it is correct to share the scope between the filter and the rest of the application, I guess it does make sense, because the filter is really part of the application.

Comment: Based on what someone said, my understanding is that the main difference between ApplicationScoped and Singleton is related to transactional and concurrency issues. If you can suggest another approach for allowing a filter to share the information with the rest of the application please let me know! thanks!

Comment: `@ApplicationScoped` CDI beans have the same scope as EJB `@Singletons`, however, they currently lack certain features you might find useful which EJB singletons posses. For example, container managed locking, startup ordering, etc. Both can be used from a servlet filter, you just need to inject them into it using @EJB and @Inject respectively.